# for loop gets to the end of the string

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop

I'm practicing Java at CodingBat.com, and I have a problem.

zipZap("azbcpzpp") returns "azbcpzpp". Expected to return "azbcpzp"

Thanks

```
// http://codingbat.com/prob/p180759
// Look for patterns like "zip" and "zap" in the string -- length-3,
// starting with 'z' and ending with 'p'. Return a string where for 
// all such words, the middle letter is gone, so "zipXzap" yields "zpXzp". 

public String zipZap(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 2)
    return str;

  String result = str.substring(0, 1);

  for (int i=1; i < (str.length()-1) ; i++) {
    if ((str.charAt(i-i) != 'z') || (str.charAt(i+1) != 'p')) 
      result += str.charAt(i);
  }

  result += str.substring(str.length()-1);  

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Also you could try using a regex.  `/z\wp/gi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the if condition to `if ((str.charAt(i - 1) != 'z') || (str.charAt(i + 1) != 'p'))`. Otherwise you always check if the char at index 0 is equal to 'z', because `i-i` is always 0.

```
public static String zipZap(String str)
{
    if (str.length() < 2)
        return str;

    String result = str.substring(0, 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < (str.length() - 1); i++)
    {
        if ((str.charAt(i - 1) != 'z') || (str.charAt(i + 1) != 'p'))
            result += str.charAt(i);
    }

    result += str.substring(str.length() - 1);

    return result;
}

Input: azbcpzpp
Output: azbcpzp
```

Comment: Also it should be `&&` else matches if even one is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String zipZap(String str) {
    String temp="";

    if(str.length()<=2){
        return str;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

        if(str.charAt(i)=='z' && str.charAt(i+2)=='p'){
            temp=temp+str.charAt(i);
            temp=temp+str.charAt(i+2);
            i=i+2;
        }
        else {
            temp=temp+str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String zipZap(String str) 
{
  String res="";
  if (str.length()<3) return str;

  for (int i=0;i<str.length()-2;i++) {

   if (str.charAt(i)=='z' && str.charAt(i+2)=='p'){
    res = res + str.charAt(i)+str.charAt(i+2);
    i+=2;
   } 
  else 
   res = res + str.charAt(i);
 }

 if (str.charAt(str.length()-3)!='z') 
   res = res + str.substring(str.length()-2);

 return res;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String zipZap(String str) {
    String g="";

    if(str.length()<=2){
        return str;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

        if(str.charAt(i)=='z' && str.charAt(i+2)=='p'){
            g=g+str.charAt(i);
            g=g+str.charAt(i+2);
            i=i+2;
        }
        else {
            g=g+str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*peek left check for 'z'* **AND** *peek right check for 'p'*, if condition meets then skip loop iteration; else add the character at the index.

```
public static String zipZap(String str) {
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!((i > 0 && str.charAt(i - 1) == 'z') &&
                (i < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'p'))) {
            answer.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return answer.toString();
}
```